# Answer question with using WSL

Tags: discussion, answers

Is this fine to answer WSL solution for a Windows10 related question which can be resolve using WSL in Windows 10?

Comment: You could try - but WSL is only supported on windows 10 pro isn't it?

Comment: sorry, I don't know that can be run exactly on which dists of Windows 10.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't recall ever hearing that... and can't find any sources for it right now. But I also don't have a copy of Home to test, so...

Comment: Depends on the question.  Why didn’t you provide us context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything technically wrong with doing so, but keep in mind that providing a WSL answer is similar to telling them to install Cygwin. It's a relatively large change to the system that should only be performed if necessary - otherwise a more native solution is preferred.

Note that before 1709 WSL was considered a dev-only/beta feature. Post-1709 it has graduated to a full feature, so this is less of an issue.

The bottom line is, if you have an answer that depends on WSL but still answers the question, go ahead and post it. It's better than nothing, and might even be preferred if they already have WSL installed. But if you also have a native answer, it's good if you can post that too :)

Comment: thanks. because sometimes WSL solutions are much shortest and which I know WSL way to answer a question :P

Comment: Be sure you answer the question that was actually asked.  If they are not running Windows 10 version 1709 your answer is unlikely to be well received if it doesn’t answer the question that was asked.